# Enforcing option hint for a statement in a while loop is not possible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, syntax, trace-flags

SQL Server 2014 Compatability level 110 uses old Cardinality Estimator.
I am trying to enforce new CE for a statement.
I am getting error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'option'."
I need to do deletions in batches.

```
while 
(   
    Select top (1) 1
    from [AdventureWorks].dbo.DatabaseLog
    option (querytraceon 2312)  --error
) > 0
begin
    delete top (10000 )
    from [AdventureWorks].dbo.DatabaseLog
end
```

-- it runs ok by itself:

```
Select top (1) 1
from [AdventureWorks].[Person].[Person]
option (querytraceon 2312)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option clause can only be used on standalone `SELECT` statements.

Not where the `SELECT` is being used as an expression.

The following examples don't allow you to specify a query hint either.

```
DECLARE @I INT = (SELECT 1 OPTION (RECOMPILE))

IF (1 = (SELECT 1 OPTION (RECOMPILE))
    PRINT '1';
```

So you will either need to

- restructure your code so that the statement you are trying to apply a query hint to is not directly embedded inline in the `WHILE` (would require either repeating the statement or wrapping it in a non inline function)
- set the trace flag on at the session level
- Use a plan guide (potentially - I haven't tested this)

For the specific example in your question you don't need the `SELECT` at all.

```
DECLARE @Dummy VARCHAR(100) ='setting initial rowcount'

WHILE @@rowcount > 0
  BEGIN
      DELETE TOP (10000 ) FROM [AdventureWorks].dbo.DatabaseLog;
  END
```

or (as this will end up deleting all rows anyway).

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [AdventureWorks].dbo.DatabaseLog;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong ... Below is the correct way of doing

```
if exists 
(   
    Select  1
    from [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Person]

)
begin
    Select  top 1 1
    from [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Person]
    option (querytraceon 2312) -- Use NEW CE Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2801413

end
else 
begin
   waitfor delay '00:00:05'
end
```

Comment: The first select statement, in exist, needs to run with option

Comment: You cant run that. What you can do is to have `dbcc traceon (2312) .. run your tsql and then dbcc traceoff(2312)`. HTH.

Comment: So I can't use WHILE and OPTION.